# Markov chain transition matrix from vector of probabilities

Tags: r, markov-chains

The complete data.frame overview:

```
'data.frame':   29 obs. of  3 variables:
$ FirmDatum : Date, format: "1982-12-31" "1983-03-31" "1983-06-30" ...
$ fittedSurv: num  0.884 0.839 0.779 0.746 0.817 ...
$ Rating    : chr  "Aa" "Aaa" "B" "Bb" ...
```

The column `fittedSurv` contains probabilities and the column `Rating` corresponds to the probability (`fittedSurv`) at that point in time.

For Markov chain transition matrix I need additional columns. Just purely resampling the single column (vector) of probabilities would not do alone.

What would be the most efficient way as far as inference is concerned?
Possible indication as to the correct R package would be sufficient - an example would be a bonus.

@Jonathan. It might well be. I suspect however that the probabilities changing over time could be bootstrapped or the vector of probabilities re-sampled so that meaningful columns of probabilities would be created. Something like:

```
A <- data.frame(X=FrameTs$Rating)
B <- data.frame(replicate(20, sample(as.character(A$X), size=100, replace = TRUE)))
```

Comment: I suspect you don't have enough information in this `data.frame` to create a real Markov chain transition matrix. Can you explain why you think you should be able to with the information given?

Comment: @Jonathan. See edit above. The replication must be wrong, since it must also contain the evolution of the probability through time I believe. Of course I don't have sufficient experience nor knowledge to assess how this could be done meaningfully.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly your data is?

Comment: fittedSurv=probability of firm defaulting over time (past data), Rating= Just assigned letters (ratings) for given probability interval, i.e. prob from 0.884 to 0.839 = Aa.

Comment: @Jonathan. The dates/times are irrelevant here.

Comment: Then I don't see how the data contains any information about the "evolution of the probability over time."

Comment: @Jonathan. You asked about dates. The actual dates don't have meaning. Only the sequence of time...since the probability of firm defaulting is the current time (the last observation)... taking into account the past observations would be beneficial for eg prediction/estimation of future paths...

Comment: @Joanthan. Thank you for looking into it, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution (which I don't trust) is:

```
A <- data.frame(X=FrameTs$Rating)
w <- FrameTs$fittedSurv/sum(FrameTs$fittedSurv)
B <- data.frame(replicate(10, sample(as.character(A$X), size=10, replace = TRUE, prob=w)))
```

which produces equally weighted matrix given the probabilities:

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   A  A  A  A  A  A  B  A  B   B
2   B  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A   A
3   A  A  A  B  C  A  A  B  B   A
4   A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A   A
5   B  A  A  A  B  A  A  A  A   B
6   A  A  B  B  B  A  A  B  A   A
......and so on...

Of course the matrix B size can be extended via replicate(1000, sample(...
```

Based on this matrix of "probabilities" (ratings) its possible to get Markov transition matrix. (package msm etc). The output figures seems to be intuitive and correct but I don't trust this this approach